# Alert Dialog box being dismissed when parameters are not correct

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, builder

I have a dialog box being displayed as soon as the `MainActivity` is started. It prompts the user to enter 2 parameters, a table number and a cover number. Then they confirm and these parameters are used to create an Order object.

However the problem I am having is that regardless of whether or not they enter the parameters the box is dismissed when they click the confirm button. I would like for the box to stay displayed and display a `Toast` message outlining the error.

Below is my code which works, but when the button is clicked the box disappears and the toast is displayed as well.

Many thanks.

```
public Dialog createDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SectionsActivity.this);

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.order_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(v);

    tableNum = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.numberEntry);
    coverNum = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.coversEntry);

    builder.setMessage("Order Information");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            if(tableNum.getText().length() != 0 && coverNum.length() != 0){
            //Create order object in here
            table = Integer.parseInt(tableNum.getText().toString());
            covers = Integer.parseInt(coverNum.getText().toString());
            Order.getInstance().setTableNumber(table);
            Order.getInstance().setCoverNumber(covers);
            created = true;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Must enter a table and cover number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    return builder.create();
}
```

EDIT:

```
if(!Order.getInstance().getCreated()){
    Dialog d = createDialog();
    d.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

 builder.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                     Button b = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String strComments = youredittext.getText().toString().trim();   // get your Textbox value here
                            if(strComments==null || strComments.length()==0)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enter General Comments", 1).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                                // do stuff if success

                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

What we are doing is, just overrding the AlertDialog Positive button, to avoid closing of button without entering values into the field

**Edit:**

```
public Dialog createDialog(){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SectionsActivity.this);

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.order_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(v);

    tableNum = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.numberEntry);
    coverNum = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.coversEntry);

    builder.setMessage("Order Information");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            if(tableNum.getText().length() != 0 && coverNum.length() != 0){
            //Create order object in here
            table = Integer.parseInt(tableNum.getText().toString());
            covers = Integer.parseInt(coverNum.getText().toString());
            Order.getInstance().setTableNumber(table);
            Order.getInstance().setCoverNumber(covers);
            created = true;
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Must enter a table and cover number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

 AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();

builder.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                     Button b = alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                     b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            String strComments = youredittext.getText().toString().trim();   // get your Textbox value here
                            if(strComments==null || strComments.length()==0)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enter General Comments", 1).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                alertDialog.dismiss();
                                // do stuff if success

                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            });

    return alertDialog ;
}
```

Comment: can your code go into my `createDialog` method? I call the builder in my application as shown in the edit above

Comment: @Javacadabra yes you can use that ,Check my edit, what i have did is place the above code as it is and then I have return alertDialog

Comment: @Javacadabra In the onClick of the Button , try to validate your Edittext's as I have provided above

Answer (score 0):

```
String tableNum="",coverNum="";
if(tableNum.gettext.toString() == "" && coverNum.gettext.toString() =="")
{
    Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enter General Comments", 1).show();
}
else 
{
    dialoge.show();
}
```